# Transition on image width does not work with window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a logo image in sticky topbar menu so when scrolling down i'm trying to change the image width using css transition but it is not working with jquery window scroll when i add the css class to logo image but when i hover on the logo image it work

my code css

```
.logo img
{
    width: 100%;
    transition:width  1s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: width 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease;
}

.transition , .logo img:hover{
    width: 50%;
    transition:width  1s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: width 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease;
}
```

js code

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){
    $j(window).on("scroll", function () {
        if ($j(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $j('.logo img').addClass('transition');
            console.log($j(this).scrollTop());
        } else {
            $j('.logo img').removeClass('transition');
            console.log('cvc');
        }
    });
});
```

please any help and many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your console actually flooded with numeric values when scrolling? If not, your event listener is not firing.

Comment: @Paul yes i'm getting the numeric values in the console

Comment: Is class `transition` added to <img>? If yes, check if `width: 50%` is not strike thru, may be `.logo img` selector is more precise so `width: 100%` overrides `.transition` style. In that case you will need to change `.transition , .logo img:hover` to `.logo img.transition , .logo img:hover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wants something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/2oktm8n4/1/) ?

Just changed your selectors a bit. Because of the inheritance of `.logo img`, `.transition` wasn't suffisant to erase `.logo img` properties.

```
.logo img
{
    width: 100%;
    transition:width  1s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: width 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease;
}

.logo .transition{
    width: 50%;
    transition:width  1s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: width 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease;
}
```